# Select String and Delete

Tags: sql, trim

I am trying to delete the "-" and everything to the left of the "-" in the following example:

Adams Mark - 1234 Main St, Anyville VA, 12345

Comment: I second @dasblinkenlight. With out your DB name, it's hard to give answer

Comment: trims, ltrim, rtrim, replace, mid.  it is a SQL database

Comment: @user12813. a sql database is not helpful. is it sql-server? mysql? oracle?

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL this would work;

```
declare @foo varchar(60) = 'Adams Mark - 1234 Main St, Anyville VA, 12345'
select substring(@foo,charindex('-',@foo,1)+1,len(@foo)-charindex('-',@foo,1) )
```

I took you quite literally and left the leading space.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do something like this .... I dont really know what you mean when you say you want to delete I guess you are trying to Update a column anyway the following will extract the desired string of you actual data.

```
Declare @Var VARCHAR(100) = 'Adams Mark - 1234 Main St, Anyville VA, 12345'

SELECT RIGHT(@Var, LEN(@Var)- CHARINDEX('-', @Var))
```

**Result String**

```
1234 Main St, Anyville VA, 12345
```

**Edit**

```
SELECT RIGHT(Column_Name, LEN(Column_Name)- CHARINDEX('-', Column_Name))
FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: this is just one example of many difference addresses in the data.  I am looking to

Comment: It will give you the all the string on the right of the very 1st occurrence of '-' in you string. If you have this string saved in a column see my Edit in the post.

Comment: I keep forgetting about LEFT and RIGHT.  I learned T-SQL a looong time ago.

Comment: @unclebrad well they say "if you dont do it you'll lose it" :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(colName, CHARINDEX(colName, '-') + 1, LEN(colName))
FROM table1;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b8114/4)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

PHP
$string = explode("-","Adams Mark - 1234 Main St, Anyville VA, 12345");
$string = trim($string[0]);

JS
var s = "Adams Mark - 1234 Main St, Anyville VA, 12345";
s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf('-'));